# Google Webmaster Tools API

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-search-console

I am attempting to pull a list of the companies that my company has registered in their Google Webmaster Tools.  I am doing this using PHP and the Google API Client Library for PHP (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/).  I have gotten everything going, except for the fact that it gives me an empty array as a result.  My code is below and any help would be greatly appreciated.

The appropriate values are filled in for client id, account, etc. and everything authenticates appropriately, as I used the same code to access the books API.

```
    <?php
    /*
     * Copyright 2013 Google Inc.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */
    session_start();
    include_once "templates/base.php";

    /************************************************
      Make an API request authenticated with a service
      account.
     ************************************************/
    require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../autoload.php');

    /************************************************
      ATTENTION: Fill in these values! You can get
      them by creating a new Service Account in the
      API console. Be sure to store the key file
      somewhere you can get to it - though in real
      operations you'd want to make sure it wasn't
      accessible from the webserver!
      The name is the email address value provided
      as part of the service account (not your
      address!)
      Make sure the Books API is enabled on this
      account as well, or the call will fail.
     ************************************************/
    $client_id = <Client ID>; //Client ID
    $service_account_name = <Service Account Name>; //Email Address
    $key_file_location = <Key Location>; //key.p12

    echo pageHeader("Service Account Access");
    if ($client_id == <Client ID>
        || !strlen($service_account_name)
        || !strlen($key_file_location)) {
      echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
    }

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
    $service = new Google_Service_Webmasters($client);

    /************************************************
      If we have an access token, we can carry on.
      Otherwise, we'll get one with the help of an
      assertion credential. In other examples the list
      of scopes was managed by the Client, but here
      we have to list them manually. We also supply
      the service account
     ************************************************/
    if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
    }
    $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'),
        $key
    );
    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
      $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }
    $_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

    /************************************************
      We're just going to make the same call as in the
      simple query as an example.
     ************************************************/

    $results = $service->sites->listSites();

    $siteList = $results->siteEntry;

var_dump($siteList);

// $optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
// $results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);
// echo "<h3>Results Of Call:</h3>";
// foreach ($results as $item) {
//   echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
// }

echo pageFooter(__FILE__);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was because I had not assigned the appropriate permissions in the Webmaster Tools Interface to the user that I was trying to connect with.  Just had to click on the gear next to each site and add the user.